# Saving the click counts of an item each item it is clicked js Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

1st sorry to say I am unable to reply comment on this thread due to 50 reputation required.
[Saving the click counts of an item each item it is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567949/saving-the-click-counts-of-an-item-each-item-it-is-clicked)

On their js script giving the error as Error: Line 14: Unexpected token }. Can anyone explain how to fix?

```
var already_clicked = [];

$('.heart').on('click', function(e) {
  var clickElement = $(this).find('.count');
  var itemId = $(this).attr("data-id");
  // changes to current view in the page
  clickElement.html(parseInt(clickElement.html(), 10) + 1);


  // send an ajax request
  $.ajax({
     url : "server.php",
     data : { count : parseInt(clickElement.html(), 10),
            id :  },
     type : "POST",
     success : function(data){
        // do something in the success
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: You don't have a value for your `id` key on line 14. I [commented on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567949/saving-the-click-counts-of-an-item-each-item-it-is-clicked#comment91650896_30568143) for you :)

Comment: I assume it's mean to be `id: itemId`

Comment: So this line should be  id :  itemId}, or  id :  "itemId"}, ?

Comment: The first one. The second would send the literal string "itemId" and that's probably not what you want. There was a good answer below showing exactly what should be changed but the author has deleted it.

Comment: Thanks, Phil sir. Could you review the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567949/saving-the-click-counts-of-an-item-each-item-it-is-clicked?answertab=active#tab-top that properly explained? Cause, the query is not connecting to the DB to incitement. As I can see you also PHP dev, can you reanswer there with full php coding including the sql query how properly work? I am using php 7.2 and not working. Thanks again.

Comment: no, I'm not inclined to do so but you are more than welcome to suggest an edit. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing